# Magento 2, Elasticsearch 8 gives error while indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, magento, magento2

I'm on Magento 2 with Elasticsearch 8 installed. The Elasticsearch is running okay and Magento is able to connect to it as well. The problem is with indexation. When I run the following command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

I get the following error:

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
{"error":"no handler found for uri [/magento2_product_1_v4/document/_mapping?include_type_name=true] and method [PUT]"}
```

Because of this, I'm not able to see products on my website. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It's only certified for elastic search 7

Comment: Yes, I downgraded to ES7 to make it work. It is not working with ES8.

Comment: Yes, It works with ES7.

Answer (score 3):

ElasticSearch 8 is not yet supported by the current Magento releases: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html